# refresh url in iframe after a submit button of another form is clicked &formatting url contents inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I reload an iframe which is already "rendered" due onload call through a javascript.
I have a page where I can add new users (by clicking submit button after entering name).
The page also displays all available users in an iframe(during onload, the iframe is "preloaded" with users). Everytime I add a new user and click on submit, the iframe(list) should also fetch the updated list automatically.

Also I am wondering how I can format the  URL "get" results in the hidden form.
Can a URL copied into an iframe be modified at the destination?

How can I do this? Please help!

This is what I have so far:

```
    <html>
    <head><title>welcome page</title>
    </head>
    <body onLoad ="subMe()">
    <script>
    function subMe(){
            document.getElementsByTagName('form')[1].submit();
    }
    function OnButton2()
{

     document.getElementById("myframe").src ='http://localhost:8000/getusers/' ;
}
    </script>
    <div align="center">
    <h1>Home</h1>

    <form name ="Form0" action= "/cgi-bin/myuser.cgi" method ="get" target="uframe" onsubmit="return OnButton2();">
    Enter Name:<input type="text" id ="name" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Create new User">
    </form>
    <iframe id="uframe" name="uframe"></iframe>
    <br>
    <div style="display: hidden;">
        <form action="http://localhost:8000/getusers/" method="get" target="myframe">
        </form>
    </div>
    <iframe id="myframe" name="myframe"></iframe>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("myFrame").src` ?

Comment: I tried what you said. Please see my post now. But nothing happens. I tried variants like document.getElementsById['myframe'].src etc but nothing just happens :(

Comment: Did you get any errors on the console?

Comment: none at all. any idea? is there any other alternative

Comment: Try this way then: `document.getElementById('iframeid').src = document.getElementById('iframeid').src`

Comment: I tried the above but the problem with that is, it simply clears the iframe. It doesnot show the updated list

Comment: So, I'm afraid the problem is elsewhere. Maybe on the code where you update the results.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is definitely as others have commented:

`document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "http://www.google.com/"`

There are a few reasons why this may not work. The most likely is that JS "same origin" policy is being violated. Try setting the src to a relative url like `"getusers/"` and watch for console errors.

Try also calling `OnButton2()` on its own and see if you can narrow down the problem.

Additionally, It sounds a lot like you are trying to load data into the DOM without reloading the page. Have you tried using [AJAX](https://www.google.ie/search?q=ajax&oq=ajax&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i59l2j5j69i60j69i62.1793j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1)? it's very simple and powerful once you get the hang of using it and will allow you to submit a form and display results in any format you wish, without using iframes or reloading the page.